# How to fetch the values from array of array

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, multidimensional-array

**I need to fetch Title summary cover values from this code. Please help me out in fetching the values of rawdata and I need to loop them.
Can someone pls help me out**

```
Array
    (
        [rawData] => Array
            (
                [csrf_hash_name] => 57b9481862e81cf2ebe9ed4e962355db
                [title] => gfgf
                [summary] => hfdhfhfdhdf
                [cover] => clockface - 2.png
                [id] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                        [1] => 
                    )


    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code below

```
<?php 

$array = array(
    "rawData" => array(
        "csrf_hash_name" => "57b9481862e81cf2ebe9ed4e962355db",
        "title" => "gfgf",
        "summary" => "hfdhfhfdhdf",
        "cover" => "clockface - 2.png",
        "id" => array(
            0 => "",
            1 => ""
        )
    )
);

foreach($array["rawData"] as $key => $arr) {
    $fetchValue = array('title', 'summary', 'cover');

    if(in_array($key, $fetchValue)) {
        $$key = $arr;
    }
}

echo $title;
echo $summary;
echo $cover;
?>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

just call it by its key:

```
$arr = Array
(
    'rawData' => Array
        (
            'csrf_hash_name' => 57b9481862e81cf2ebe9ed4e962355db,
            'title' => gfgf,
            'summary' => hfdhfhfdhdf,
            'cover' => clockface - 2.png,
            'id' => Array
                (
                    0 => '',
                    1 => ''
                )


);
```

and then use

```
$title = $arr['rawData']['title'];
$summary = $arr['rawData']['summary'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$array = array(
    "rawData" => array(
        "csrf_hash_name" => "57b9481862e81cf2ebe9ed4e962355db",
        "title" => "gfgf",
        "summary" => "hfdhfhfdhdf",
        "cover" => "clockface - 2.png",
        "id" => array(
            0 => "",
            1 => ""
        )
    )
);
$arr2 = array();
foreach($array["rawData"] as $key => $arr) {
    $fetchValue = array('title', 'summary', 'cover');
    if (in_array($key, $fetchValue)) {
        $arr2[$key] = $arr;
    }
}
extract($arr2);

echo $title;
echo '<br/>';
echo $summary;
echo '<br/>';
echo $cover;
?>
```